# Sync My Documents folder, using Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, documents

I'm trying to set up a backup feature for the users in a Active Directory Domain.

The wish is for the clients "my docuemnts" folder to sync to a folder on the file server.

Is this doable using Active Directory only, or do one need any third party applications?

If its doable, what steps is needed to set this up, on the server, and clients?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is call "Folder Redirection".  It managed through Group Policy.  Search for "folder redirection" on Microsoft TechNet or Google, and you will find tons of information on how to do this.

You do not need any third-party applications, and you need at minimum one Windows Server installation and one Windows Client (XP, Vista, 7) installation.

Comment: Does the group policy-solution demand roaming profiles on the clients?

Comment: No.  Folder Redirection works independently of roaming profiles.  If you do use roaming profiles, however, using folder redirection will make your profiles smaller (thus loading and saving faster) because the "My Documents" folder will no longer roam with the profile.

Comment: Please check out www.serverfault.com. It is a system administrator-centric sister to this site, and it is the more appropriate place for questions like this.